# ¿Cómo puedo insertar un nuevo nodo a una lista enlazada simple y que se ordene numéricamente al insertar?

Tags: java

Aqui presento la clase nodo, donde se encuentran los metodos get y set, cada uno de ellos permiten lanzar los datos, además de que se encuenta el metodo constructor

Esta es el la clase nodo

```
public class Nodo {
private String nombrePaciente;
private int horaCita;
private String urgente;
```

//Variable para enlazar los nodos;

```
private com.mycompany.agendalistas.Nodo siguiente;
```

//Constructor que inicializamos el valor de los atributos

```
public void Nodo(){
this.nombrePaciente="";
this.horaCita=0;
this.urgente="";
this.siguiente=null;
```

}

```
//Métodos get y set para loa atributos

    public String geturgente(){
    return urgente;
    }
    public int gethoraCita(){
    return horaCita;
    }
    public void seturgente(String urge){
    this.urgente=urge;
    }
    public String getnombrePaciente(){
    return nombrePaciente;
    }
    public void sethoraCita(int valor){
    this.horaCita=valor;
    }
    public void setNombrePaciente( String nom){
    this.nombrePaciente=nom;
    }

    public com.mycompany.agendalistas.Nodo getSiguiente(){
    return siguiente;
    }
    public void setSiguiente(com.mycompany.agendalistas.Nodo siguiente){
    this.siguiente=siguiente;
    }

}
```

Ahora dentro del frm, se encuentra un boton que realiza un evento.
Necesito que se inserte un nodo y se coloque en orden numérico, este es lo que tengo.

```
private void btnAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
  //Definir un nuevo nodo
   Nodo nuevo =new Nodo();
   //Agregamos los valores al nodo.
   nuevo.setNombrePaciente(txtNombre.getText());
   nuevo.sethoraCita(Integer.parseInt(this.CmbHora.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    if (this.chkSi.isSelected()) {
        nuevo.seturgente("Si");
    }else if (this.chkNo.isSelected()) {
        nuevo.seturgente("No");
    }
   
    //consulta si la lista esta vacia.
    if(esVacia()){
    //Inicializa la lista agregando como inicio al nuevo nodo.
    inicio=nuevo;
    //Si no, va agragando los nodos al inicio de la lista
    }else{
  Nodo aux=inicio;
  Nodo anterior =aux;
  while(aux!=null){
       //Caso 1. El nodo a insertar es menor que el primero.
        if (nuevo.gethoraCita()<aux.gethoraCita() & anterior==inicio) {
            nuevo.setSiguiente(aux);
            aux=nuevo;
            inicio=nuevo;
            
            //Caso 2. El nodo a insertar es mayor.
        }else if(nuevo.gethoraCita()>aux.gethoraCita()){
         Nodo siguiente=aux.getSiguiente();
         aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
         nuevo.setSiguiente(siguiente);
        }
   aux=aux.getSiguiente();
  }
      }
    mostrar();
  tamaño ++;
}
```

El diseño del frm permite que el boton de agregar, agregue los datos de una cita, esta cita debe ser insertada y ordenada dependiendo de la hora de registro.

Comment: pon tu clase nodo como código para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ya lo deje en la respuesta siguiente, muchas gracias por ayudar. Ruslan López

Comment: Si con eso te auto respondes está bien, si no colócalo en la zona de pregunta

Comment: No sé como editar mi pregunta

Comment: Aquí arriba de la secciónd e comentarios te salen unos links, el segundo dice editar

Comment: Listo, Ojala me puedas ayudar :(

Comment: Podrías poner la implementación del método mostrar?

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que tiene una variable global llamada inicio, te dejo la logica en este codigo:

```
public void funcion() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        Nodo nuevo = new Nodo();
        nuevo.setNombrePaciente(scan.next());
        nuevo.setHoraCita(scan.nextInt());
        if (inicio == null) {
            inicio = nuevo;
        } else {
            Nodo anterior = inicio;
            Nodo posterior;
            while (true) {
                if (nuevo.getHoraCita() == anterior.getHoraCita()) {
                    System.out.println("Ya existe una cita agendada a esta hora");
                    break;
                }
                if (nuevo.getHoraCita() > anterior.getHoraCita()) {
                    posterior = anterior.getSiguiente();
                    if (posterior == null) {
                        anterior.setSiguiente(nuevo);
                        break;
                    } else if (nuevo.getHoraCita() < posterior.getHoraCita()) {
                        anterior.setSiguiente(nuevo);
                        nuevo.setSiguiente(posterior);
                        break;
                    }
                    anterior = anterior.getSiguiente();
                } else {
                    nuevo.setSiguiente(inicio);
                    inicio = nuevo;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(inicio.toString());
    }
}
```

Lo hice funcionar en la consola ya que no queria hacer un form, pero solo seria cuestion de cambiar los scan.next() por tus campos de form y agregar unas cosas que borre para mayor claridad, ya que no afectaban en la logica (tambien borre los comentarios para comprimir mas el codigo), te recomiendo que empieces a utilizar buenas practicas, como nombrar bien a tus metodos y a tus propiedades. Me imagino que es un trabajo de escuela, ya que existen muchas formas mejores para hacer esto, como los List (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) sobreescribiendo el metodo compareTo y usando sort(), o los punteros (esta documentacion te la debo).

Edit: El codigo lo hice para que me pidiera valores sin parar, obviamente tambien esa parte tendrias que adaptarla a tu codigo.